# jqTouch with ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms, jqtouch

The form tag that wraps all ASP.NET webform applications is causing jqTouch to completely break (as in, nothing works - none of the transitions, effects, etc). Has anyone gotten jqTouch to work with a ASP.NET webforms application?

Comment: If you're not actually using serverside code to build the web application, then you can remove the `<form>` tag entirely ...

Answer (score 0):

For mobile development you can user Jquery mobile. it was developed exclusive for mobile and have a lot of features to mobile events. Is more tiny, faster and easy to use. I had use this with form tag, you just need to main the main , and the head page on each aspx. 
You have all reference here.

http://jquerymobile.com/

And can open the api with google chrome browser

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/

Regards